# SQL Server query runs more time from code than from Management Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I know might take some time to execute.

When I run it from SQL Server Management Studio, it takes about 12-15 minutes to complete and that is fine.

But when I run it from my C# asp.net web application it crashes after 40 minutes and it still doesn't complete.

What it the difference between the two runs and how can I fix it to run from my application?

Comment: **[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)** Parameter sniffing or concurrent access and blocking

Comment: Have you tried capture times using Profiler?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't help that much...

Comment: Maybe something in connection string?

Comment: are you sure it is crashing on the stored procedure call OR is it possibly crashing afterwards (once you retrieved the data from SQL)? What are you doing with the data after (any loops)?

Comment: The case is simple, I just call the stored procedure from my code and it runs for 40 minutes and not all rows it supposed to update are updated, and when I run it from the SQL studio it runs for 15 minutes and all rows are updated.

Comment: Are you really having a stored procedure that runs for 15 minutes? With that being said, have you tried using profiler to see how the procedure is being called from the app, there must be something different.

Comment: The 15 minutes are not an issue because it does a lot of actions on a lot of records. We've tried using a profiler, but it didn't point to any issue

Comment: @LiranFriedman There must be an issue and hence the difference in time. Have you tried to recompile the stored procedure? Have you also seen that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265259/sp-taking-15-minutes-but-the-same-query-when-executed-returns-results-in-1-2-min

Comment: @LiranFriedman Great, I hope that it will help you solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the crash we've increased the timeout in the IIS.
@Apostrofix has posted [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265259/sp-taking-15-minutes-but-the-same-query-when-executed-returns-results-in-1-2-min) with an unexpected solution, that I wasn't familiar with before.

A quote from this post is:

> The recommended fix for most situations (though it depends on the
>   structure of your query and sproc) is to NOT use your parameters
>   directly in your queries, but rather store them into local variables
>   and then use those variables in your queries.

Comment: That recommended fix (storing parameters into local variables) made the execution time of my SP drop from 4'30'' to 15'' !!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try increasing the timeout from connection string in your **web config** :
just change the value of timeout key.

```
<add key="Inf:DatabaseCommandTimeoutSeconds" value="20" />
```

Comment: I know I can increase the timeout, but I don't want the query to run that long, it is a bad workaround to do so...

Comment: Can you paste your database query?? and tell me how much data are you working with? Maybe i can optimize the query.

Comment: Ok. So you can look into to optimize your query yourself. Use "Include Actual Execution Plan" option in SSMS for viewing time used by your each part of query.