# C#: DbType.String versus DbType.AnsiString

Tags: c#, dbtype

I have taken over some C# code.

The code is hitting a database with some `SQL` which uses parameters.

All of the string parameters are typed as `DbType.AnsiString` instead of `DbType.String`.

Why would you use `DbType.AnsiString` instead of `DbType.String`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

AnsiString
A variable-length stream of non-Unicode characters ranging between 1 and 8,000 characters.

String
A type representing Unicode character strings.

In database:

nchar and nvarchar is unicode

char and varchar is non-unicode

Comment: +1. Why would anyone NOE use AnsiString of it IS an ansi non unicode string in the database? Eludes me as logic.

Comment: Is `DbType.AnsiString` a sub-set of `DbType.String`?

Comment: Short: multilingual support for Chinese, Japanese, Korean and so on

Comment: Unicode may be represented by different encodings - what's the one in question?

Answer (score 16):

You would use ansistring instead of string to avoid implicit conversions in your SQL Server database.

i.e. when you pass a string variable into MSSQL it appears as nvarchar(max). Given the fact a well designed database in MSSQL may use varchars as opposed to nvarchars by default (unless there is a business requirement for non latin character sets).

A string variable in this case will cause an implicit conversion in the database. This can then render the engine unable to use certain indexes and perform full table scans (one of the roots of all evil for db performance)

Answer (score 5):

> Why would you use DbType.AnsiString instead of DbType.String?

Short answer: When your `SqlParameter` is pointing to a `varchar` (or `char`) database column you would use `DbType.AnsiString`. When you point to a `nvarchar` column, use `DbType.String` because its `Unicode`.

Longer answer:
If these are not mapped accurately (e.g. pointing `DbType.String` to a `varchar(nn)` column, you will see `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` warnings in your query plans as described by Pinal Dave here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/11/sql-server-how-to-fix-convert_implicit-warnings/

*In my case* the `SqlParameter.Size` property also seemed to be important: to completely eliminate `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` warnings I had to map `DbType` *and* `Size` correctly. The default `Size` if omitted "is inferred from the actual size of the specified parameter value"(1) which will usually mismatch the real column size definition and that raises a warning as well.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I don't get `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` warning when I omit `Size` for varchar column. Though I didn't try to pass a string longer than max database column length.

Comment: Vasily, thanks for the feedback. I made a slight edit to note that size could be a factor (it was in my case) but maybe not in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

See how to solve the problem in C# with Dapper:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(string), DbType.AnsiString);
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(String), DbType.AnsiString);
```