# How can I insert Special char from textbox in to SQL table (Special char like 's , " or like ♥ ♫ )..?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

```
string sql = "insert into tblmain values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtPost.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "')";
```

If the user inserts `My name's first later is D !` in txtPost, then it gives error that `'`s are not allowed.
Can you please send me the code to accept this type of character from textbox in .net (C#).

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of string concatenations. Your code is open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: As @SonerGönül said you are making your site vulnerable for SQL injection. Use `SqlCommand` instead. You can use `"insert into tblmain values(?,?,?)"`. And then use `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

You sample is the book example of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in most pure form. `'` closes the previous quote and the rest of SQL command is interpreted differently from what you expect.

There is no excuses to not using [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)  when dealing with non-hardcoded values and `SqlConnection` directly.

Also check these [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) for mre details. Approximate sample (need more fields and not showing exception handling):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblmain values(@name")", connection);
  command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.String);
  command.Parameters["@name"].Value = customerID;
  connection.Open();
  Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
}
```

The second problem you may hit is if you pick wrong field type for the text - to be able to store characters you want you need Unicode string. Check out [C#: DbType.String versus DbType.AnsiString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229671/c-dbtype-string-versus-dbtype-ansistring) post for details.